# Can't get method to exit and skip turn properly on keypress

Tags: c#

So I'm building this RPG turn based game for a class. I'm not trying to get my homework done for me, but this one problem is REALLY spinning me out, I've been at this for like 3 hours and I can't figure out how to fix this problem.

Essentially, I have an update method that controls whos turn it is (either the player or the computer)

```
public bool Update()
        {
            // clears console for a fresh start
            Console.Clear();
           

            //branch who's turn it is and add a line indicating so
            if (playerTurn)
            {
                //print that it's the player's turn
                Console.WriteLine("It's Your Turn to Attack!");
              

  
                //run the player turn
                PlayerTurn();

            }
            else 
            {
                //print the rivals turn label
                Console.WriteLine("It's the Enemy's Turn to Attack!");
             
            }


            //run the rivals turn
             RivalsTurn();

            {
            }
        

            //end game check
            return EndTurn();
        }
```

Then, I have the player turn method ---

```
 void PlayerTurn()
        {
            // print instructions to select an attacker
            Console.WriteLine($"Select which character will attack!\n(1) To Select {playerArray[0].Name()}\n(2) To Select {playerArray[1].Name()}\n(3) To Select {playerArray[2].Name()}\n(4) to view your teams current status\n(5) To Heal An Ally");
            // Loop until an attacker is chosen
          
            while (Attacker == null)
            {
                // use num 1-3 to select player party member that is the attacker
                ConsoleKeyInfo k = Console.ReadKey();
                if (k.KeyChar == '1')
                {
                    Attacker = playerArray[0];
                    Console.WriteLine($"\nYou've chosen to attack with {Attacker.Name()}");

          


                }
                else if (k.KeyChar == '2')
                {
                    Attacker = playerArray[1];
                    Console.WriteLine($"You've chosen to attack with {Attacker.Name()}");
             
                    
                 

                }
                else if (k.KeyChar == '3')
                {
                    Attacker = playerArray[2];
                    Console.WriteLine($"You've chosen to attack with {Attacker.Name()}");

                }
                else if(k.KeyChar == '4')
                {
                    PrintParties();
                    continue;

                } else if (k.KeyChar == '5') {
                    HealAlly();
                    break;
                }


               

                // start a new line after user input
                Console.WriteLine();
              
                // Data Validation: make sure the key typed is a valid key
                if (k.KeyChar < '1' || k.KeyChar > '5')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter (1), (2), or (3) to select your attacking character. Press (4) to view your stats, and (5) to Heal an Ally");
                    continue;
                } 
                else // convert from key input (1-3) to array element space (0-2)
                    curSelection = int.Parse(k.KeyChar.ToString()) - 1;
                {
                    
                }


              if (Attacker.GetHP() <= 0)
                {
                //check to make sure the selected character is alive HP > 0
                   //print the attackers name
                    //character's dead choose again
                    Console.WriteLine($"{Attacker.Name()} is dead! Choose someone who is alive!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter (1), (2), or (3) to select your attacking character. Press (4) to view your stats, and (5) to Heal an Ally");
                    Attacker = null;
             
                } 
                
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{Attacker.Name()} will attack!");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
           
            }

 
    

            //print instructions for choosing a rival.
            Console.WriteLine($"Select which enemy to attack!\n(1) To Attack {enemyArray[0].Name()}\n(2) To Attack {enemyArray[1].Name()}\n(3) To Attack {enemyArray[2].Name()}\n(4) To see the Enemies Current Stats.");

            //loop until a defender is choosen
            while (Defender == null)
            {
                // use 1-3 to select player party member that is the attacker
                ConsoleKeyInfo k = Console.ReadKey();
                if (k.KeyChar == '1')
                {
                    Defender = enemyArray[0];
                    Console.WriteLine($"\nYou will attack {Defender.Name()}");

                } else if(k.KeyChar == '2') {
                    Defender = enemyArray[1];
                    Console.WriteLine($"\nYou will attack {Defender.Name()}");
                }
                else if (k.KeyChar == '3')
                {
                    Defender = enemyArray[2];
                    Console.WriteLine($"\nYou will attack {Defender.Name()}");
                } else if (k.KeyChar == '4')
                {
                    playerTurn = false;
                    PrintParties();
                    playerTurn = true;
                }
                { }
                //add a new line aft er the user input
                Console.WriteLine();

                // Data Validation: make sure the key typed is a valid key
                if (k.KeyChar < '1' || k.KeyChar > '3')
                {
                    // repeat instructions
                    Console.WriteLine("Select an enemy to attack by pressing either 1, 2, or 3.\n");
                    // loop again
                    continue;
                }
                else // convert from key input (1-3) to array element space (0-2)
                    curSelection = int.Parse(k.KeyChar.ToString()) - 1; //minus one to use as index
                //check to make sure the selected character is alive HP > 0
                    //print the defenders name
                    //assign the selected character as the defender
                if (Defender.GetHP() <= 0)
                {
                    //print instructions again        
                    Console.WriteLine($"{Defender.Name()} is already dead! Pick another enemy!");
                    Console.WriteLine("Select an enemy to attack by pressing either 1, 2, or 3.\n");
                    Defender = null;
                } else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{Attacker.Name()} attacks {Defender.Name()}!");
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                 

                }
            }

            //damage the defender by the attacker's Strength value
            Defender.ApplyDamage(Attacker.GetStrength());
          


            //change color for rival team
            Console.BackgroundColor = Attacker.GetTeamColor();
            //print the new rival's health
            Console.WriteLine($"{Defender.Name()} was hit by {Attacker.Name()}! {Defender.Name()} now only has {Defender.GetHP()} HP!");
       

            EndTurn();

            //change color back for normal
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            //pause for 2 seconds
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            //reset attacker/defender for next attack
            Attacker = null;
            Defender = null;
        }
```

What I am trying to do is when the player selects "5" and runs the HealAlly() Method, I want the program to Take the users next input (who to heal), tell the player whether or not they can heal (if the character is either dead or full health) and then switch turns.

Instead, the code jumps back to the middle of the PlayerTurn method and tries to execute from there, but since the Attacker was never set (the user hit 5 so they didn't pick an Attacker) the game will crash.

Here is the HealAlly() method:

```
 void HealAlly()
        {
            float healing = 3;
          
    
                while (Healee == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nWhich Ally Do You Want To Heal?");
                    Console.WriteLine($"(1) for {playerArray[0].Name()}\n(2) for {playerArray[1].Name()}\n(3) for {playerArray[2].Name()}");
                    // use 1-3 to select player party member that is being healed
                    ConsoleKeyInfo k = Console.ReadKey();
                    if (k.KeyChar == '1')
                    {
                        Healee = playerArray[0];
                        Console.WriteLine($"\nYou will heal {Healee.Name()}");
                        Console.WriteLine("Healing...");


                    }
                    else if (k.KeyChar == '2')
                    {
                        Healee = playerArray[1];
                        Console.WriteLine($"\nYou will heal {Healee.Name()}");
                        Console.WriteLine("Healing...");

                    }
                    else if (k.KeyChar == '3')
                    {
                        Healee = playerArray[2];
                        Console.WriteLine($"\nYou will heal {Healee.Name()}");
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        Console.WriteLine("Healing...");


                    }
                    else if (k.KeyChar > 3 || k.KeyChar < 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Choose which character you want to heal!");
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (Healee.GetHP() >= 12)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        Console.WriteLine($"{Healee.Name()} has full health! You can't heal them!");
                    EndTurn();

                }
                    else if (Healee.GetHP() <= 0)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        Console.WriteLine($"{Healee.Name()} is dead! You can't heal them!");
                    EndTurn();
                   
                }
                    else
                    {
                        Healee.ApplyHealing(healing);
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        Console.WriteLine($"{Healee.Name()} has been healed, and now has {Healee.GetHP()} HP!");
                    EndTurn();
                 
                }
```

I thought that adding the call to EndTurn() at the end of the HealAlly() method would cause the turn to end, but instead all it does is give me the delay message and then shoot back to the middle of the PlayerTurn() method. I'm sure it's because there was no Attacker set, but that's not what I want, because I don't want the player to be able to attack after healing.

Here is the EndTurn() method if that will help

```
  bool EndTurn()
        {
            //switch turns for next loop
            playerTurn = !playerTurn;

            // loop through players to see if they're alive and store in a variable counting if they're alive or not
    

            bool playersAlive = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < playerArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (playerArray[0].GetHP() <= 0 && playerArray[1].GetHP() <= 0 && playerArray[2].GetHP() <= 0)
                {
                    playersAlive = false;
                }

            }

            // same for rivals
            bool rivalsAlive = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < enemyArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (enemyArray[0].GetHP() <= 0 && enemyArray[1].GetHP() <= 0 && enemyArray[2].GetHP() <= 0)
                {
                    rivalsAlive = false;
                }

            }
            // if both have things alive start the next round, pause the game, and return true to continue playing
            if (playersAlive && rivalsAlive)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Next Round Starts in 5 seconds");
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
             
                return true;
            } // if only the players have members alive you win
            else if (playersAlive)
            {
                //clear screen for results
                Console.Clear();
                //print you've won and parties
                Console.WriteLine("Congrats you win! Final Standings:");
                playerTurn = false;
                PrintParties();
                playerTurn = true;
                PrintParties();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Console.WriteLine("Thanks For Playing!");
                Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key to Play Again");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
                Init();
                return false;
             
            } // only rival members are alive
            else
            {
                //clear screen for results
                Console.Clear();
                //Print you've lost and parties
                Console.WriteLine("You Lose :( Final Standings:");
                playerTurn = false;
                PrintParties();
                playerTurn = true;
                PrintParties();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Console.WriteLine("Thanks For Playing!");
                Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key to Play Again");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
                Init();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

This is bugging me, can anyone help?

Comment: Did you debug your code and check where it deviates from the expected flow?

Comment: I've been trying to for like 3 hours... 

As explained, what ends up happening is the code executes the HealAlly() method, and then returns to the line after it -- I can't figure out how to make it skip all of that and just go directly to the computers turn. I've tried adding EndTurn() methods at the end of it, and it still just goes back to the line below HealAlly() in the PlayerTurn() method.

I can keep struggling to figure it out, but I figured I would see if anyone knows what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you would like help from the Stack Overflow community, one requirement of a question like this one is to take the time to produce a [mcve] and post that in your question instead of snippets from your actual program. There's way too much code in the above that's not relevant, and yet the code above cannot be compiled and run to reproduce the problem you have. Please fix your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 void PlayerTurn()
 {
    // ...
    while (Attacker == null)
    {
         // ...
         if (k.KeyChar == '5') {
                HealAlly();
                break;
            }
    }

    // ...code that depends on Attacker...
 }
```

The `break` statement here only causes the flow to break out of the `while` loop and continue with the code the depends on Attacker. If you want to leave the `PlayerTurn()` method altogether, replace the `break;` with a `return;`